# Makefile: Default Value of Variable that is set but has null value

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, make, gnu-make

I have a Makefile that has a variable that needs to have a default value in case when variable is unset or if set but has null value.

How can I achieve this?

I need this, as I invoke make inside a shell script and the value required by the makefile can be passed from the shell as $1. And to pass this to makefile I have to set it inside bash-script.

---

Ideas: (Not elegant) Inside the bash script the variable could be checked if its set but has null value, in that case it can be unset.

---

## Snippets

Note: the following won't work if the variable are not defined in the terminal, as they are set in the bash script.

### Makefile

```
dSourceP?=$(shell pwd)
Source?=$(notdir $(wildcard $(dSourceP)/*.md))
```

### Bash Script

```
make all dSourceP="${1}" Source="${2}"
```

### Terminal

```
bash ./MyScript.sh
bash ./MyScript.sh /home/nikhil/MyDocs
bash ./MyScript.sh /home/nikhil/MyDocs index.md
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since you’re using GNU `make`, you could use [the `?=` operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html#Setting):

```
FOO ?= bar
```

but that doesn’t deal with pre-existing null (or rather, empty) values. The following deals with absent and empty values:

```
ifndef FOO
override FOO = bar
endif

test:
    echo "$(FOO)"

.PHONY: test
```

(Make sure line 6 starts with a real tab.)

You’d call this using

```
make FOO=blah
```

to set a value. `make` or `make FOO=` will end up setting `FOO` to `bar`; you need `override` [to override variables set on the command-line](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html#Overriding).